# Applying "for" sentences into each rows in DataFrame pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

*I re-posted this question since I missed some important part in my previous questions.

I have DataFrame like below

```
Email-adress                                  Body
  abcd@gmail           Hi, I am xxxx. ======= ABCD corporation Chris =======
 asdff@gmail           Thank you for the information. Bruh bruh. ------CDDD inc  name-----
```

And from this Body column in the DF, I would like to delete all the signatures so the output is like below

```
output
    Email-adress                                  Body
      abcd@gmail           Hi, I am xxxx. 
     asdff@gmail           Thank you for the information. Bruh bruh.
```

I have gotten an example of code like below

```
stri=stri.split()
for i in range(len(stri)):
    if ('====' in stri[i]) or ('----' in stri[i]):
        stri=stri[:i]
        break

print(' '.join(stri))
```

But this is by putting "stri"= text in Body and this method applies into only one row. 
But I would like to know how to apply this into each of rows so I can get rid of all signature from every rows.

Comment: Do those signatures always start with exactly '----' or '===='?

Comment: Not 100% but as I made a list of them, 90% are starting from them.
And since I have gotten a list, I apply the method in different form of start afterwards as well.

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

**Using regex:**

```
def remove_sign(row):
    return re.sub(r"=.*=|-.*-", "", row)

df['Body'] = df['Body'].apply(remove_sign)
```

**df:**

```
    Email-adress    Body
0   abcd@gmail      Hi, I am xxxx.
1   asdff@gmail     Thank you for the information. Bruh bruh.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#searches for alpha numeric characters, space, comma and period 
df.Body.str.extract(r'([\w,.\s]+)')

     0
0   Hi, I am xxxx.
1   Thank you for the information. Bruh bruh.
```

OR :

```
 #look for characters that start before = or -
 #the ? after the + sign gets the least amount ... non-greedy mode

 df['Body'] = df.Body.str.extract(r'(.+?(?=[=-]))')

    Email-adress    Body
0   abcd@gmail      Hi, I am xxxx.
1   asdff@gmail     Thank you for the information. Bruh bruh.
```